# Meteor with accounts-google package - Login not working on iOS (Safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, meteor

I'm having an issue testing my meteor app/site on mobile devices (Safari in iOS). It's making use of the accounts-google/accounts-ui packages.

On desktop browsers I'm able to authenticate and log in via Google perfectly. When testing on mobile Safari after I click 'Sign in with Google' I'm able to authenticate with Google, but end up stuck on the  '_oauth/google?close' page, with the following message: "Login completed. Click here to close this window." Clicking the link does nothing.

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appears there's a bug/issue with iOS 8 that's interfering with the 'popup' style of login, not only for google but for a handful of other services: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1044445#1044445 (Apple dev account required to see the above). Long story short, it's an unresolved iOS 8 issue.

There are a couple of github issues discussing the above:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2720

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2639

The workaround: add 'loginStyle: "redirect"' to the service configuration, ie:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "google",
    clientId: "xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    secret: "123xyz",
    loginStyle: "redirect"
});
```

**Note**

You will also need to update your Google app in the developer console to include the new redirect URI, ie: http://example.com/_oauth/google

Comment: This works for me. Thanks so much buddy. As easy az changing login style to redirect.

Comment: If the user is browing in private mode in chrome or safari, redirect does not work however. Becuase no localstorage. [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser)

Comment: You don't need to insert a new record to make this change.  You can just edit your existing Google service configuration document in the `meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration` collection.